# variables defined in a %time statement inside a method are not accessible after the statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

This seems to work fine -

```
%time a = "abc"
print(a)

CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 19.1 µs
abc
```

This doesn't -

```
def func():
    %time b = "abc"
    print(b)

func()

CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 31 µs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-57f7d48952b8> in <module>()
      3     print(b)
      4 
----> 5 func()

<ipython-input-8-57f7d48952b8> in func()
      1 def func():
      2     get_ipython().magic(u'time b = "abc"')
----> 3     print(b)
      4 
      5 func()

NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

Here's a link to a [notebook](https://gist.github.com/jayantj/2ead360ffb326f5e5e78e9e58b8a153e)

I'm using python 2.7, haven't tried it with python3 yet.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost certain this is an IPython bug. [Reported here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9892).

```
In [31]: def func():
    ...:     a = 2
    ...:     %time b = 1
    ...:     print(locals())
    ...:     print a
    ...:     print b

In [32]: func()
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 6.2 µs
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-08a2da4138f6> in <module>()
----> 1 func()

<ipython-input-31-13da62c18a7e> in func()
      4     print(locals())
      5     print a
----> 6     print b
      7
      8

NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Quoting the response from takluyver in your github issue here -

Sorry, that's a longstanding limitation in the way Python works. Local variables are not looked up from a dictionary the way global variables are, so dynamically executed code modifying the local namespace doesn't work as you'd expect.

So I expect the best way to deal with it would be 
`b = locals()['b']`
 `print(b)`

Comment: see this github discussion: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9892

Answer (score 1):

It works in Python 3, if you write the `%time` after the equal sign, like this:

```
def func():
    a = 2
    b = %time 1
    print(locals())
    print(a)
    print(b)

func()
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 6 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 6 µs
Wall time: 10.3 µs
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
2
1
```